# Jpeg to pdf with itextsharp is cutted on top and bottom

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, twain

I use the iTextSharp assembly in order to convert jpg to pdf.

My jpg is scanned by a twain ( A4).
The jpg is good.

I convert my png in pdf with this:

```
Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new System.IO.FileStream(this._fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Scanners.Twain.GetImage(i), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);  
doc.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height));
doc.NewPage();
doc.Add(img);
doc.Close();
```

My problem is thaht the pdf resulted is a bit ( a bit) cutted on the top and on the bottom.
Why ?

How can i avoid this ?

Thanks a lot,

Seuxin

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify otherwise, a `Document` has a `Margin` of 36 on all sides. You can remove them by:

```
doc.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as Chris Haas suggests, but you can use this is an alternative:

```
img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
```

This way, the `img` doesn't take into account the margins of the document, but it is added at the lower-left corner of the page.